# input submit throws 404 for control not found in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have published an MVC application to the server path '/iapps/ebiz'. The application works perfectly on localhost. The @Ajax.Action link is working as expected for the 'Get' operation and but '' is not finding the Post method for the controller and is throwing error code 404.

[image]

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink(
                     "Add Email",
                    "GetEditEmail","Customer",
                              new { CommunicationLocation = "add" },
                     new AjaxOptions()
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "Get",
                                UpdateTargetId = "DivEmailContainer",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                            },
                      new { @class = "btn btn-success" })      </td>



 @using (Html.BeginForm("PostEditEmail","Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmEmail", id = "frmEmail" }))
    {

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" /> 
      <!-- This one is going "/iapps/Customer" but suppose to be "/iapps/eBiz/Customer"

    }
```

### controller

```
 [HttpGet]
 public PartialViewResult GetEditEmail(string CommunicationLocation)
 {
 }
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("PostEditEmail")]
 public PartialViewResult PostEditEmail(string Actiontype,  FormCollection col)
 {
 }
```

Route Mapping

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

### HTML shows

```
<form action="/iapps/ebiz/Customer/PostEditEmail?Length=8" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#DivEmailContainer" id="frmEmail" method="post" name="frmEmail" novalidate="novalidate" _lpchecked="1">
```

### Update: 04/08/2015 3:30PM

Issue fixed if add if I add `/eBiz/` (backslash) after eBiz in the browser. If `/eBiz` and post is not working.  How to fix this?

This trailingslash for base url issue.

Comment: Did you create the virtual directory path as ebiz

Answer (score 0):

you had given the Route attribute as [Route("PostEditEmail")] so it will point to the URL

> **/iapps/ebiz/PostEditEmail**

so that only your getting 404 error. Try this

```
[Route("Customer/PostEditEmail")]
```

Comment: But It is going `iapps/customer/PostEditEmail`. completely ignoring `ebiz`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `area` parameter in `Html.BeginForm`.Try the following.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostEditEmail","Customer", new { area = "eBiz" }, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmEmail", id = "frmEmail" }))
    {    
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
    }
```

Even if your controller is not under Area folder, you should add `new { area = "" }` in `Html.BeginForm` method